# How To Include Only Part Of A File With PHP

Tags: php, html

is there a way to include only part of a file using the PHP's include function?
Say inside the document is normal html and the only parts i want are those marked with div id="content" how would i include just the "content" portion?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, one thing you could do is, place that HTML part in a PHP function and call it in your script.

Comment: Have you tried using ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

is not possible such thing, i suggest you to use template files

the with with templates is something like this

html.tpl.php:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <?php echo $html_headers; ?>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php echo print_content_div(); ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

my_php_page.php:

```
 $html_headers='your headers';
 include 'content_div.php';
 include 'html.tpl.php';
```

content_div.php:

```
<?php
function print_content_div(){
   echo "<div id='content'>Your content here</div>";
}
```

this way you can write huge pages without repeating your code